# date pipe issue on IE10 - 'Intl' is undefined

Tags: angular, es5-shim

I have the following simple example that uses the Angular 2 date pipe which works fine in IE11 but fails on IE10:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: 'my date: {{ myDate | date }}'
})
export class AppComponent {
  myDate: Date = new Date();
}
```

One IE10, it errors out with `'Intl' is undefined`. The shim was properly loaded just like the quickstart example.

Here's the plunker - http://plnkr.co/edit/rJIAay1mRXnnFtNvmM7x?p=preview

If you turn on IE10 emulation mode in the F12 tool then the error occurs. How do I get around this issue on the IE10 browser?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The (only) reasonable explanation is that `Intl` isn't polyfilled.

As `core-js` documentation [states](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js#missing-polyfills),

> ECMA-402 `Intl` is missed because of size. You can use [this polyfill](https://github.com/andyearnshaw/Intl.js/).

Comment: I included the cdn but still got the error. any ideas why? http://plnkr.co/edit/mn97YETZAwRsv5803yY4?p=preview. thanks.

Comment: Because [it's not correct](https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=Intl.~locale.en). Check it in IE10.