# Angularjs Date format in GET Response

Tags: angularjs

I want to display date format like this **02-jan-2018**

**GET Method**

```
$scope.allReport = function() {
       $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'api/admin/report'
        }).success( function (data) {
                $scope.data = data.data;
               console.log($scope.data);
          }).error(function (response){
                console.log("error");  
       });
    }
```

**Response**

```
0:{
created_at:"2018-03-02 00:00:00"
cuid:21
id:64
name:"my"
status:"D"
time:"07:01 PM"
updated_at:"2018-03-02 00:00:00"
}

1:{
created_at:"2018-03-02 00:00:00"
cuid:22
id:65
name:"my1"
status:"P"
time:"06:59 PM"
updated_at:"2018-03-02 00:00:00"
}
```

I display like this 
**View**

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in data | filter:{name:searchbyname}">
    <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
    <td>{{user.name}}</td>
    <td>{{user.created_at | date : "dd-MMM-yyyy" }}</td>
    <td>{{user.status}}</td>
</tr>
```

i want to display like created_at this in **02-jan-2018**

Comment: what's problem in that?

Comment: Same format only displaying

Comment: check my answer that might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this, you are getting the date in string format.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<table>
<tr ng-repeat="user in data | filter:{name:searchbyname}">
    <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
    <td>{{user.name}}</td>
    <td>{{user.created_at | date : "dd-MMM-yyyy" }}</td>
    <td>{{user.status}}</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.data= [{
    created_at: "2018-03-02 00:00:00",
    cuid: 21,
    id: 64,
    name: "my",
    status: "D",
    time: "07:01 PM",
    updated_at: "2018-03-02 00:00:00",
    }, {
        created_at: "2018-03-02 00:00:00",
        cuid: 22,
        id: 65,
        name: "my1",
        status: "P",
        time: "06:59 PM",
        updated_at: "2018-03-02 00:00:00"
    }];
    
    $scope.data = $scope.data.map(obj =>{
     obj.created_at  = new Date(obj.created_at); // converting string to date
     return obj;
    })
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you getting the response? `$scope.data = data.data;` after this step, you are trying right not outside?

Comment: How to get in POST API

Comment: use $http.post for calling post apis.

Comment: Here i want to apply $scope.data = response.data.data; 
                        $scope.name = $scope.data.name;
                        $scope.created_at = $scope.data.created_at; change date format

Comment: you cant do `$scope.data.name` because $scope.data is not an object is an array. You don't need to store the formatted date in DB because It may create problems while performing sort or search operations.

Comment: NO FOR THIS I WNAT TO DO $scope.created_at = $scope.data.created_at;

Answer (score 0):

An advice form a friend plz use moment you will have a lot of problems with date pipe in angular and moment is more flexible ;)

[Angular2 date pipe does not work in IE 11 and edge 13/14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39728481/angular2-date-pipe-does-not-work-in-ie-11-and-edge-13-14)

[date pipe issue on IE10 - 'Intl' is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40367759/date-pipe-issue-on-ie10-intl-is-undefined)

https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment

```
{{now | momentPipe:'DD-MMM-YYYY'}}
```