# 'Intl' is undefined - SharePoint

Tags: fullcalendar, sharepoint-2013, internet-explorer-10, fullcalendar-4

I am trying to use [fullcalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/) in my SharePoint application.

The website is set to open with IE10 compatibility mode, and I am getting the error `'Intl' is undefined` when the page is loaded.

The [same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40367759/date-pipe-issue-on-ie10-intl-is-undefined) had been reported from within angular.

Is there a workaround that I can use?

Comment: This is not suprising. https://fullcalendar.io/getting-help says `The latest version of FullCalendar is compatible with Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Edge, and IE 11+.`. You could see whether an older version of fullCalendar (e.g. v3) would work, or you can change the compatibility mode of your application - assuming that doesn't break anything else. Are you using an old version of Sharepoint or something?

Comment: I agree with the suggestion given by the ADyson. As it is mentioned in the documentation. If possible for you than try to use IE 11 instead of IE 10 may help to fix this error.